# RDP over multiple ssh tunnels

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, rdp, tunnel, ssh-tunnel

I would like to access a remote desktop that is sitting inside office, below is my setup

- my laptop(Ubuntu) from home connected to internet (A)
- public Ubuntu instance connected to internet(B)
- 3)from B there is a reverse ssh tunnel created to a office ubuntu
- system (C).
- 4)from office ubuntu system (C) I can RDP to another office windows
- system (D) to 3389 port.

How I access the system

- from my laptop(A) I connect to public ubuntu instance(B) via ssh (22)
- then from public (B) I do ssh -p someport user@localhost and this gets connected to office ubuntu system(C).

How do I access RDP of office windows system (D) to my laptop(A).?

Answer (score 2):

ok finally found solution..

Executed below command in office Ubuntu system (C) to create a reverse proxy.

```
ssh -fN -R public_ubuntu(B)IP:3389:office_windows_system_(D)_IP:3389 user@public_ubuntu(B)IP
```

Then executed below command in my Laptop to create a tunnel from public_ubuntu(B) to my lap(A).

```
ssh -L 3389:localhost:3333 user@public_ubuntu(B)
```

then opened RDP client in my laptop(A) and entered

> localhost:3333

that's it..desktop came.. :-)

Hope someone could find it useful.